# How can we prove there will be at least a vertex with in-degree of zero in Directed Acyclic graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, directed-acyclic-graphs, topological-sort

I can see the hypothesis true intuitively but, mathematically I am not able to prove. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Let this graph have n vertices.

Suppose we reverse all the edges, then we are trying to prove there is a vertex with an out-degree of zero.

If not, then simply start anywhere and travel along n edges (always possible as every vertex as non-zero out-degree).  Therefore we have visited n+1 vertices - so at least 2 of them must be the same (pigeon hole principle), and therefore we have found a cycle in your acyclic graph.

Comment: Good answer. OP probably doesn't care, but an infinite DAG doesn't need to have any vertices with indegree zero. E.g. one node per integer, each pointing to the node associated with the next integer.

Answer (score 0):

Let us prove it mathematically.

Consider the directed graph G = (V, E), where V denotes the collection of vertices and E represents the set of edges.

Assume, for the sake of contradiction, that there is a DAG G with no vertex of degree zero.

Let v represent any vertex in G. There are no vertices with in-degree zero, hence every vertex must have at least one incoming edge.

Let u be a vertex for which a directed edge (u, v) exists. Given that v has an incoming edge, we can conclude that u must exist. However, since u is the origin of the edge (u, v), it also needs to have an incoming edge.

Following this logic, there must be another vertex u with an incoming edge (u, v) for each vertex v.

There is a limit to the number of vertices in the graph, therefore this procedure cannot go on forever. As a result, we have to finally arrive at a vertex that has no incoming edges.

Our hypothesis that there must be a DAG with no vertex of in-degree zero must be incorrect in light of this contradiction. There must be at least one vertex with in-degree zero in every DAG as a result.